# How to update PHP query to reflect form choices live using JQuery & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that takes four inputs: `$query_sort, $query_time , $query_date , $query_rows`, with everything as a combo box with options except `$query_rows` which is a text box.

After taking this input, which is selected by default, PHP processes this and puts in in a query which returns a table (not shown in example for conciseness, but it does return a table successfully) from a MySQL database. Problem is, since I don't want to have a `submit` function or want to have the page refresh and want to be able to add a Document Listener instead to show the changes live, so that if I changed the `$query_sort` variable, it would automatically execute the query and return a table without having to refresh or press a button.

I have been able to get a Document Listener working, but not the update. Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
   $('#query_sort').on('change', function(event) {
       var query_sort = $(this).val();

       if(query_sort) {
           request = $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "_php/nds/return_criteria_checkbox.php",
               data: {query_sort: query_sort}
           })
            .done(function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
           });
       }
    });
});
```

One of my select form:

```
<select id = "query_sort" name = "query_sort">
    <option value = "time_desc" class = "query_sort_combobox_select"> Time Added (DESC)</option>
    <option value = "time_asec" class = "query_sort_combobox_select"> Time Added (ASEC)</option>
</select>
```

So I did confirm it does run that bit of code, since I had it have an alert pop up if I change that. Here's my PHP form:

```php
$query_sort_crit = $_POST['query_sort'];

// Some code that converts $query_sort_crit to $query_sort by using switch to convert to something I can use as a criteria.

$query = ""; //some query that appends $query_sort. In the actual code, there would an actual query.
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc(){
    echo $row["title"];
}
```

I can confirm the PHP code works, since I have the four inputs set to default in the `switch` case, which gives me the `$row["title]` that matches the default criteria. I think my problem lies in the `request = $.ajax` part, since that doesn't seem to work at all.

Just in case, here's my file structure:

```
. admin (subdomain)
├── _php
|   ├── nds
|   |   └─ return_criteria_checkbox.php
├── nds
└   └─ nds.php
```

As an added question, do I need to have seperate `EventListeners` for every `input` in my `form`? Or can I just reference the `form` despite having multiple and diverse `input type` inside?

Comment: What are you doing with the response of the ajax call? There is no .done() or .fail() at all.

Comment: @HimanshuPant I did have a `.done` segment, doesn't that execute if the ajax call is done, not the ajax call itself?

Comment: No, the .done callback is run when a successful(200-209) response is returned, pass the data parameter to the done callback and just do a console.log(data) in your callback, and hit me back with what's printed.

Comment: @HimanshuPant I added it above, it does give me a log. It says `XHR | GET *domain*/_php/nds/return_criteria_checkbox.php?query_sort=time_asec` but doesn't change the display.

Comment: It doesn't change the display because the only thing you told it to do was write a log. If you want to change the content of your page you need to write some JavaScript code to do that

Answer (score 0):

Given our conversation, it appears that you php action is responding and your ajax request is being successfully sent, but the appears to be that you have got the wrong idea about ajax. I believe what you're trying to do is send the query request using ajax, get the table(which I believe is partial html) and display that to the user. You would do that like this. 
In your html add an empty div with a unique id, I've called it TableContainer.

```
$(function() {
   $('#query_sort').on('change', function(event) {
       var query_sort = $(this).val();

       if(query_sort) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "_php/nds/return_criteria_checkbox.php",
               data: {query_sort: query_sort}
           })
            .done(function(data, textStatus){
                //This is just to check that the server actually responded with some data, and not just an empty success code.
                if(textStatus !== "nocontent"){
                    $("#TableContainer").html(data);
                }
            });
       }
    });
});
```

Now to answer your second question, you can just add a unique identifier(selector), (be it a data attribute or a unique class) to your inputs and add the event listener to that, You might also want to change the `data` option to just `$("selectorForForm").serialize()`

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This doesn't change anything; The table stays the same, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you look in the developer console if the request is going through fine and if a response is coming in, do a preview of it. you would see it in the Network section of devtools in chrome.

Comment: If I put in your code, it returns a 404, but if I retain mine with the `.done` part, It does give me a 200. Nothing on the response tab though on Firefox, although everything else seems to work.

Comment: There we have it. ` var request = $.ajax({//Code here})` returns a promise that's what the .done() callback is for. Now with my code you're getting a 404. Open developer tools. Look at the request that went, right click and open on new tab. Check if the url is actually okay or not because that means that the url provided to ajax did not return anything, it could be incorrect.

Comment: It does give me a 200 now for some reason, probably because I made a typo or something, but it doesn't refresh the table. And the param tab on firefox does show `query_sort = time_asec`

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the response tab on firefox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196103/discussion-between-dragonsnap-and-himanshu-pant).